# How change the size of sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i want to change the scale of sprite like a paper in 'Paper Toss' game.

'Paper Toss' is the game is available on the App store.i want to make a sprite like a paper and change the scale of sprite like a paper in 'paper Toss';

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why dont you set its scale property ????

Comment: do you play 'paper toss' game..? if yes them i want no make a animation like a paper goes to basket in 'paper toss' game.

Comment: if yes then how make animation like a paper goes in basket?

Comment: As per my suggestion this game is not 3d but graphics are 3d

Comment: I don't think so because the bounce (high, direction, etc.) change depending on the distance. They must work with a 3D physic motor and so in a 3D environment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the setScale method.

```
[sprite setScale:1.5];
```

In this case, the scale is set to 1.5 times.

Answer (score 2):

```
[sprite runAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration scale:0.4f];
```

This is the working code